# Matplotlib - polyfit trendline seems to overlap itself and look fuzzy/unclear

Tags: python, matplotlib, trendline

I'm trying to plot some trendlines for some data that I have. Problem is that it looks fuzzy and it seems to overlap on itself if I use dotted or dashed styles.

Not sure why, but the lines also look like there's no anti-aliasing done -- they look jagged. Trying to produce the exact same graph in Excel gives clean lines.

Using other line styles doesn't help; nor does increasing the spacing by adding dashes=(1,5) or similar. Even if you increase plot size or change linewidth - it still overlaps.

Here's the code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy
from scipy import stats

radon = [49.6,61.7,58.7,64.1,59.4,64.6,65.4,65.3,65.5,66.0,50.5,64.8,71.9,
71.9,60.4,54.4,50.9,58.1,52.6,55.6,56.6,41.6,43.0,33.0,41.5,53.5,52.2,45.1,
46.8,63.0,73.8,61.3,44.4,39.3,38.2,45.4,39.9,36.3,41.0,38.5,35.4,40.2,11.3,
34.7,24.2,24.5,32.1,26.3,23.6,32.1,27.5,39.0,24.9,22.0,18.2,23.0,21.1,15.4,
13.9,10.2,26.4,18.2,16.6]

tout = [-2.57,-3.31,-0.63,-0.60,0.39,-1.64,-7.62,-1.90,-0.35,-4.88,-1.27,
-0.23,-6.99,-2.87,-12.27,-11.90,-9.42,-4.10,-3.15,0.81,3.87,-11.41,-9.47,
0.25,-6.81,-13.70,-16.41,-14.14,-9.70,-10.32,-21.83,-26.55,-16.88,-6.85,
4.03,-7.89,-6.53,-3.96,-6.09,-3.15,-0.51,-2.62,8.13,2.08,0.58,1.99,-6.64,
-12.13,-4.95,-2.99,-4.81,-0.88,0.28,-1.44,1.92,3.73,0.21,1.11,6.83,13.31,
7.04,1.46,1.78]

# start and end index for data
a = [0,21,42]
b = [20,41,62]

n = 0   # just a counter

# set font family
hfont = {'family':'Arial'}
plt.rcParams.update({'font.family': 'Arial', 'font.size':12})

# set axis minor tick marks
plt.axes().yaxis.set_minor_locator(mtick.MultipleLocator(4))
plt.axes().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mtick.MultipleLocator(2))
plt.axes().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.0f%%'))

# config axis labels
plt.xlabel("Outdoor Temperature", **hfont)
plt.ylabel("Radiator on %", **hfont)

# set line and marker types and colors
marker = ['o', 's', 'x']
marker_facecolor = ['None', 'k', 'None']
names = ['Manual Control', 'Enforced Schedule', 'Occupancy-based']
lines = [':','--','-']
line_spacing = [[1, 5], [5, 5], [0, 0]]
transparency = [1, 0.75, 1]

for i,j in zip(a,b):
    # get x and y
    x = numpy.array(tout[i:j])
    y = numpy.array(radon[i:j])

    # set axis ranges
    plt.ylim(0, 100)
    plt.xlim(-30, 20)

    # plot data
    plt.plot(x, y, marker[n],markeredgewidth=0.75
    ,markeredgecolor='k',markerfacecolor=marker_facecolor[n],
    alpha=transparency[n],label=names[n])

    # perform regressions
    z = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    p = numpy.poly1d(z)

    # plot trendline
    plt.plot(x,p(x),'k%s' % lines[n], linewidth=0.85)

    # increment counter
    n+=1

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
leg = plt.legend()
leg.get_frame().set_edgecolor('k')

plt.savefig('tout_vs_radon.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Here's the result of the above code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXmY3.png
(don't have enough reputation to post image, sorry)

You can see the trendline overlapping itself in the center for dotted or dashed styles. I'm using matplotlib v3.0.3 and Python v3.6.5 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key would be to plot the array in a **sorted** fashion. Else, the line will jump back and forth and overlap itself.

```
order = np.argsort(x)
plt.plot(x[order],p(x[order]), ..)
```

Complete code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np

radon = [49.6,61.7,58.7,64.1,59.4,64.6,65.4,65.3,65.5,66.0,50.5,64.8,71.9,
71.9,60.4,54.4,50.9,58.1,52.6,55.6,56.6,41.6,43.0,33.0,41.5,53.5,52.2,45.1,
46.8,63.0,73.8,61.3,44.4,39.3,38.2,45.4,39.9,36.3,41.0,38.5,35.4,40.2,11.3,
34.7,24.2,24.5,32.1,26.3,23.6,32.1,27.5,39.0,24.9,22.0,18.2,23.0,21.1,15.4,
13.9,10.2,26.4,18.2,16.6]

tout = [-2.57,-3.31,-0.63,-0.60,0.39,-1.64,-7.62,-1.90,-0.35,-4.88,-1.27,
-0.23,-6.99,-2.87,-12.27,-11.90,-9.42,-4.10,-3.15,0.81,3.87,-11.41,-9.47,
0.25,-6.81,-13.70,-16.41,-14.14,-9.70,-10.32,-21.83,-26.55,-16.88,-6.85,
4.03,-7.89,-6.53,-3.96,-6.09,-3.15,-0.51,-2.62,8.13,2.08,0.58,1.99,-6.64,
-12.13,-4.95,-2.99,-4.81,-0.88,0.28,-1.44,1.92,3.73,0.21,1.11,6.83,13.31,
7.04,1.46,1.78]

# start and end index for data
a = [0,21,42]
b = [20,41,62]

n = 0   # just a counter

# set font family
hfont = {'family':'Arial'}
plt.rcParams.update({'font.family': 'Arial', 'font.size':12})

# set axis minor tick marks
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_locator(mtick.MultipleLocator(4))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mtick.MultipleLocator(2))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.0f%%'))

# config axis labels
plt.xlabel("Outdoor Temperature", **hfont)
plt.ylabel("Radiator on %", **hfont)

# set line and marker types and colors
marker = ['o', 's', 'x']
marker_facecolor = ['None', 'k', 'None']
names = ['Manual Control', 'Enforced Schedule', 'Occupancy-based']
lines = [':','--','-']
line_spacing = [[1, 5], [5, 5], [0, 0]]
transparency = [1, 0.75, 1]

for i,j in zip(a,b):
    # get x and y
    x = np.array(tout[i:j])
    y = np.array(radon[i:j])

    # set axis ranges
    plt.ylim(0, 100)
    plt.xlim(-30, 20)

    # plot data
    plt.plot(x, y, marker[n],markeredgewidth=0.75,
             markeredgecolor='k',markerfacecolor=marker_facecolor[n],
             alpha=transparency[n],label=names[n])

    # perform regressions
    z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    p = np.poly1d(z)

    # plot trendline
    order = np.argsort(x)
    plt.plot(x[order],p(x[order]),'k%s' % lines[n], linewidth=0.85)

    # increment counter
    n+=1

plt.show()
```

[image]